# I am getting timeout error in the following code. How to reduce the complexity of the code?

Tags: java

**You are provided with a string s and an integer k.**

*You have to find another string t which satisfies the following conditions:*

t must be a subsequence of s.
        Every character t in  must occur at least k times.
        The length of t must be as large as possible.
        If there are multiple strings for t with largest possible length, pick the 
        lexicographically smallest one.
        For example, let's say the string is s=hackerrank and k=2.

```
    The solution for this is t=akrrak. Here t is a subsequence of k, it conta 
    ins the characters a,k and r  repeated at least k=2 times. And, it is the 
    only longest possible subsequence that satisfies the conditions.

    Input Format

    The first line contains a string s denoting the original string. 
    The second line contains an integer k.

    Constraints

    String s will only contain lowercase English characters.
    Every input will have a valid solution.
    Output Format

    Print the string t on a single line.

    Sample Input 0

    hackerrank
    2
    Sample Output 0

    akrrak
    Explanation 0

    In 'akrrak', all the characters occur exactly 2 times.
```

I have used 2 for loops for comparing each character with the whole string. if the count for any character is greater than value of k then that particular character is stored in an char array and is printed as a result. 
           I have used null in method as return value. How to return the string as a result?? How to resolve the timeout issues??
        How to reduce the complexity of the program??

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

  static String subsequenceAgain(String s, int k) {
    // Complete this function
    char ch[] = new char[s.length()]; //initializing character array
    int len = s.length(); //calculating length of string

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) // making comparison with each character
          count++;
      }
      if (count >= k) {
        ch[i] = s.charAt(i);
        System.out.print(ch[i]); // subsequence to be printed
      }
    }

    return "null";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String s = in .next();
    int k = in .nextInt();
    String result = subsequenceAgain(s, k);

    in .close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I don't think he needs a debugger, honestly.

Comment: Was there any test case/scenario mentioned where you could get two sub-sequences with max length?

Comment: Code indentation

Comment: Did you copy this or type it from memory?  In one place it says *t* should be a subsequence of *s*, in another it says *t* should be a subsequence of *k* (which doesn't even make sense), and in the example solution, *t* is not a subsequence of anything.

Answer (score 0):

> How to return the string as a result??

Right now you are printing the solution as you go.  Instead, you need to save it to a variable.  I think a `StringBuilder` would be appropriate here.  You can declare it like this:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
```

You can add to it like this:

```
result.append(ch[i]);
```

And return the underlying String like this:

```
return result.toString();
```

> How to resolve the timeout issues??

The code you have shouldn't be timing out, unless your input is extremely large or your timeout period is extremely short.

> How to reduce the complexity of the program??

The complexity of your current program appears to be O(n^2), which isn't unreasonable.  There are ways to make it O(n) but unless your input is very large I don't think it would really make a difference.